# Plugin (.jar) is unable to access mysql database on local server

Tags: java, ssl, ubuntu-20.04, mysql-8.0, bungeecord

I am trying to create a BungeeCord minecraft server. As it is going to be offline-mode one, I needed to add special bungeecord plugin that saves users` passwords in MySql database. When launching, console gives me 2 errors. The first one is:

```
07:22:34 [SEVERE] Fri Aug 13 07:22:34 UTC 2021 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without
server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and
5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't
set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting
useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

I am not sure if that one is highly important. However, I've tried to disable ssl server-side (as I am unable to edit plugin - I do only have its .jar) by deleting .pem files and adding `skip_ssl` and `ssl = 0` to `mysqld.cnf`, and checked if it worked by executing `show global variables like '%ssl%';` and the output was

```
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                       | Value    |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
| admin_ssl_ca                        |          |
| admin_ssl_capath                    |          |
| admin_ssl_cert                      |          |
| admin_ssl_cipher                    |          |
| admin_ssl_crl                       |          |
| admin_ssl_crlpath                   |          |
| admin_ssl_key                       |          |
| have_openssl                        | DISABLED |
| have_ssl                            | DISABLED |
| mysqlx_ssl_ca                       |          |
| mysqlx_ssl_capath                   |          |
| mysqlx_ssl_cert                     |          |
| mysqlx_ssl_cipher                   |          |
| mysqlx_ssl_crl                      |          |
| mysqlx_ssl_crlpath                  |          |
| mysqlx_ssl_key                      |          |
| performance_schema_show_processlist | OFF      |
| ssl_ca                              |          |
| ssl_capath                          |          |
| ssl_cert                            |          |
| ssl_cipher                          |          |
| ssl_crl                             |          |
| ssl_crlpath                         |          |
| ssl_fips_mode                       | OFF      |
| ssl_key                             |          |
+-------------------------------------+----------+
```

Unluckily, nothing has changed and the 1st error still appears.

The second one is

```
07:22:38 [WARNING] Exception encountered when loading plugin: MoonVKAuth
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at \b\.\a\.\m\.onEnable(:5473)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:265)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:287)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:67)
    at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute async query 
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\w\.\y\(:34770)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\w\.\q\(:34298)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\e\.\y\(:52017)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\e\.\y\(:26050)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\n\.\o\.\y\(:9266)
    at \b\.\a\.\g\.\y\.<clinit>(:28073)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error to MySql connection - 127.0.0.1/users
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at ?.\ez\(Unknown Source)
    at \j\.\y\.\m\.\z\.\j\.\ez\(Unknown Source)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\w\.\y\(:8528)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error to MySql connection - 127.0.0.1/users
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\e\.\qu\(:23143)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\e\.\qs\(:15109)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\w\.\y\(:33750)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\w\.\d\(:49294)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2095)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2020)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:428)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:136)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:107)
    at ?.\eq\(Unknown Source)
    at \j\.\y\.\m\.\z\.\j\.\eq\(Unknown Source)
    at \b\.\a\.\i\.\z\.\q\.\e\.\qu\(:22264)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ambassador4ik'@'localhost'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3933)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:864)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1707)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1217)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2036)
    ... 24 more
```

I guess the most important here is `Access denied for user 'ambassador4ik'@'localhost'`, so I checked if I can access the database with that user via console, and I could:

```
ambassador4ik@instance-2:~$ mysql -uambassador4ik -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 25
Server version: 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I really ran out of ideas and it would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: *As root*, try `grant all on FOO.* to 'ambassador4ik'@'localhost' ;` (I don't know what the database is in question)

Comment: I solved the second issue by setting root password to empty. I guess mysql uses some kind of encryption that is unreadable for the plugin.